# Meaning of PORTS column of Docker container ls

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm getting this value on the `PORTS` column of a `docker container ls` entry (a container for a react app served by Nginx):

```
PORTS
80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:40000->40000/tcp, :::40000->40000/tcp
```

I know the second part is IPv4 mapping and the third is IPv6. I don't understand the meaning of the `80/tcp`, but I think it's what really makes the app accessible from the internet, because if I use mapping "80:80" it works, but now with "40000:40000" it doesn't.

My project has a structure like this, so it can build multiple projects at once with compose:

```
|
|- client (a React app)
|  |- Dockerfile-client
|- .env.prod
|- docker-compose.yml
```

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile-client
      context: ./ # so the .env.prod file can be used by React
    container_name: client
    env_file:
      - .env.prod # enabled to apply CLIENT_PORT var to Dockerfile-client
    ports:
      - "${CLIENT_PORT}:${CLIENT_PORT}"
  # others
```

All the variables are defined in `.env.prod` (`CLIENT_PORT` is 40000), and I run compose like `docker compose --env-file .env.prod up", and it doesn't bring errors.

Here's the Dockerfile that builds the client container:

```
# build env
FROM node:13.13-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./client/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY ./client/ ./
COPY ./.env.prod ./
RUN mv ./.env.prod ./.env
RUN npm run build

# production env
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE ${CLIENT_PORT}
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

It would all work fine if I mapped "80:80", but my problem is how is that `80/tcp` there in the `ls` output when there's no "80" to be seen in the files? Might it be because of Nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`80/tcp` is from nginx which listens by default on this port.

Correct port mapping in this case will be `4000:80`

OR

If you want nginx to listen on other port like `4000` update `listen` parameter in [nginx.conf](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/#nginx-conf) file to that port

```
http {
    server {
        listen 4000;

        }
}
```

And then use port mapping as `4000:4000`